# How to run Cordova app logic when pushed to the background?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

In Cordova android app, we observed that app processing is stopped when pushed to background.
My app has to keep on running the logic even when it is not active.
Is there a way to run the app processing even when pushed to background ?